# Guardar en formato lista resultados de python en html

Tags: html, python

estoy tratando de guardar en us.html el contenido de la variable x del final de codigo, pero solo me guarda la ultima linea de la lista, se que tiene que ver con algo de guardar en lista o guardar como formato de lista pero no se como hacer en este codigo.

```python
def html_create(result):

    template = open("template.html","r")
    output = open("us.html","w")
    text = template.read().format(get_result = result)
    html = output.write(text)
    template.close()
    output.close()

imp_ports = open('scan_ports.txt','r')
regex = '[0-9]+/[\w.]+\s*[\w.]+\s*[\w.]+.[\w.]+'
list_port = []
for line2 in imp_ports:
    line2 = line2.rstrip()
    x = re.findall('[0-9]+/[\w.]+\s*[\w.]+\s*[\w.]+.[\w.]+', line2)
    if len(x) > 0 :
        if x[0] not in list_port:
            list_port.append(x[0])
            html_create(x[0])
            print (x[0])
```

Este es el ejemplo de como se ve en la terminal y como se ve en el html:

[image: Este es el ejemplo de como se ve en la terminal y como se ve en el html]

Comment: Si **llamas a `html_create` en cada iteración del `for`** , en cada una de ellas se sobreescribe el fichero y al final solo contendrá la información generada en la última iteración.... Debería usar `list_port` para crear el html, llamando a `html_create` cuando termine el ciclo, no dentro de él.

Comment: Por otro lado solo tienes en cuenta el primer resultado de la lista resultado de `re.findall`....

Comment: lo que dices es cierto en cuanto a que list_port contiene los resultados el problema de guardar list_port es que me guarda todo en desorder de se ve de esta manera.                                                                                             ['21/tcp open ftp', '22/tcp open ssh', '25/tcp open smtp', '26/tcp open rsftp', '80/tcp open http', '110/tcp open pop3', '113/tcp closed ident', '143/tcp open imap', '443/tcp open https', '465/tcp open smtps', '587/tcp open submission', '993/tcp open imaps', '995/tcp open pop3s', '8080/tcp open http-proxy', '8443/tcp open https-alt']

Comment: como puedo cambar re.findall para que no me guarde solo un resultado si no todos los que se generen? gracias por tu respuesta..

Comment: No tengo muy claro que pretendes conseguir, `re.findall` retorna una lista con todas las coincidencias que encuentre  aunque tu solo tienes en cuenta la primera de cada línea (x[0]) ¿Qué quieres decir con que   list_port está desordenada? El orden en la lista se mantiene, ese orden es debido al orden de las lineas del fichero sobre el que aplicas re.findal linea a linea. Si pudieras crear un [mcve] es posible que sea más fácil ayudar.

Comment: Entiendo, te comento todo entonces, tengo un script que usa nmap y guarda los resultados en un txt, solo se guarda la lista de puertos abiertos y se imprime en pantalla en lista, esto lo hago con la expresion regular, ahora quiero guardar esos mismos datos pero en el html, lo unico que pasa es que al guardar los tados en el html se guardan asi como te mostre arriba, abro el html y los resultados ya no se ven  en una lista sino desordenados, voy a ver como subo un ejemplo del resultado para que me entiendas mejor, :)

Comment: listo, en la imagen que subi, te muestro como se ven los resultados en la terminal y como se ven en el html, quiero que los datos del html se vean en lista ordenados como en la terminal :´(

Answer (score 0):

Al margen de que lo que te han dicho en los comentarios (que tienes que llamar a `html_create()` una sola vez pasándole la lista de resultados, en lugar de llamarle una vez en cada iteración del bucle), creo que el problema está en que no tienes claro quizás cómo generar un HTML "presentable" a partir de esa lista.

La creación del "html" que estás llevando a cabo es demasiado simple. Según veo te limitas a abrir un "template.html" (cuyo contenido no muestras, pero podemos intuir a la vista del resultado), leerlo en una cadena, y aplicarle `.format()` a la cadena pasándole la lista `result` como parámetro.

Aunque no muestras el contenido de "template.html", dado que no usas ningún sistema de templates sofisticado como jinja2 o similares, entiendo que ese template no puede contener dentro bucles para procesar la lista que le estás pasando, sino que todo lo más contendrá algo el estilo:

```
<html><head></head>
<body>
  {get_result} <!-- Lugar donde irá el resultado -->
</body>
</html>
```

Python se limitará a sustituir el `{get_result}` por la lista que le pasas, para lo cual generará la versión string de la lista, que es algo como:

```
['21/tcp open ftp', '22/tcp open ssh', '25/tcp open smtp', '26/tcp open rsftp', '80/tcp open http', '110/tcp open pop3', '113/tcp closed ident', '143/tcp open imap', '443/tcp open https', '465/tcp open smtps', '587/tcp open submission', '993/tcp open imaps', '995/tcp open pop3s', '8080/tcp open http-proxy', '8443/tcp open https-alt']
```

Por lo que el HTML resultante será algo así:

```
<html><head></head>
<body>
  ['21/tcp open ftp', '22/tcp open ssh', '25/tcp open smtp', '26/tcp open rsftp', '80/tcp open http', '110/tcp open pop3', '113/tcp closed ident', '143/tcp open imap', '443/tcp open https', '465/tcp open smtps', '587/tcp open submission', '993/tcp open imaps', '995/tcp open pop3s', '8080/tcp open http-proxy', '8443/tcp open https-alt']
</body>
</html>
```

que se vería más o menos como muestras en tu captura de pantalla.

Quizás esperabas que generase alguna tabla donde todo apareciera organizado por columnas, similar a lo que ves en la terminal. Python no hará tal cosa automáticamente a menos que lo programes de algún modo.

Por ejemplo, podrías procesar la lista que recibes, para generar una cadena en la que esos elementos aparezcan separados por `<br>`, y pasar esa cadena al template:

```
def html_create(result):
    template = open("template.html","r")
    output = open("us.html","w")
    text = template.read().format(get_result = "<br>\n".join(result))
    html = output.write(text)
    template.close()
    output.close()
```

Usando este método, el HTML resultante sería así (suponiendo el "template.html" de antes):

```
<html><head></head>
<body>
21/tcp open ftp<br>
22/tcp open ssh<br>
25/tcp open smtp<br>
26/tcp open rsftp<br>
80/tcp open http<br>
110/tcp open pop3<br>
113/tcp closed ident<br>
143/tcp open imap<br>
443/tcp open https<br>
465/tcp open smtps<br>
587/tcp open submission<br>
993/tcp open imaps<br>
995/tcp open pop3s<br>
8080/tcp open http-proxy<br>
8443/tcp open https-alt
</body>
</html>
```

este HTML, aún sin ser ninguna maravilla, se verá mejor que el que te salía a tí. Al menos mostrará cada cadena en una línea, muy similar a lo que ves en la terminal.

Lo ideal sería separar cada una de las cadenas que componen las líneas en sus tres componentes, envolver cada uno de ellos en `<td></td>`, y la línea completa en `<tr></tr>`, y el conjunto final en `<table></table>`, para generar así una salida tabulada. Pero eso te lo dejo como ejercicio ;-)